# how to receive message from MessageQueue

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue

I have problem receiving message of my type from MessageQueue.
Here is the code:

```
MyClass myClassObject = null;
 var msmq = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\myqueuename")
                       {Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] {typeof (MyClass)})};
 var receive = msmq.Receive(new TimeSpan(20000000000));

            if (receive != null)
            {
                 myClassObject = (MyClass)receive.Body;

            }
```

I wish in the end in myClassObject to have the data.

```
 [DataContract]
    public class 
            MyClass
    {

        [DataMember]
        public long? Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
.....
    }
```

What am I missing?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I get this error: Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format.    at System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)
   at System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to verify the App.config files both on client and server. The exception you wrote indicates that probably this message serialization format is not associated with your bindings.